# UART HDL question

Tags: vhdl, uart

For the following [TinyTx HDL code](http://hamsterworks.co.nz/mediawiki/index.php/TinyTx#tiny_rs232_tx.vhd) , why

> shift_reg <= '1' & data & '0';

and

> shift_reg <= '0' & shift_reg(9 downto 1);

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity tiny_rs232_tx is
    Port ( clk         : in  STD_LOGIC;
       bit_tick    : in  STD_LOGIC;
       data        : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
       data_enable : in  STD_LOGIC;
       tx          : out STD_LOGIC := '1';
       busy        : out STD_LOGIC );
end tiny_rs232_tx;

architecture Behavioral of tiny_rs232_tx is
signal shift_reg  : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) := (others => '1');
signal i_busy     : std_logic;

begin
    busy <= i_busy;
    with shift_reg select i_busy <= '0' when "0000000000", '1' when others;

clk_proc: process(clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
        if i_busy = '0' and data_enable = '1' then
            shift_reg <= '1' & data & '0';
        end if;             

        if bit_tick = '1' then
            if i_busy = '1' then
                tx <= shift_reg(0);
                shift_reg <= '0' & shift_reg(9 downto 1);
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

**Could anyone think of ways to reduce the resource usage even further than the original coding approach ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the two lines are forming the data shift register which converts a parallel data bus to a serial one.

With UART there is a start bit (`0`), followed by up to 9 bits of data (exact number is predetermined, typically 7 or 8 bits), and finished up with a stop bit (`1`). Furthermore the data is shifted out LSB first. In your example it is an 8bit data, so I will use that for the rest of the answer.

Based on this it should be more clear what the line `'1' & data & '0';` does.
It simply concatenates a 10 bit parallel data bus consisting of a  `1` as the MSB (stop bit), and a `0` as the LSB (start bit), with the 8bits of data in between (LSB of data closest to start bit).

To form the shift register, where the LSB leaves first, the construct `shift_reg <= '0' & shift_reg(9 downto 1);` is used. This takes that 10 bit number, moves every bit down one toward the LSB. You can see how bit 1 of `shift_reg` moves into bit 0, and so on. A `0` is added to the MSB to keep the data 10bits wide.

You can see from `tx <= shift_reg(0);` that at the same time as the data is shifted, the LSB is not lost, it is moved into the `tx` output register which presents it at the output of the module.

---

As a side note, really it should be a `1` that is added to the MSB when shifting. This way you could leave the shifter running (it would continue clocking out stop bits) and save some logic in the process.

Comment: However, the approach in computing the 'i_busy' might not work if the data are all zeroes.  What do you think ?

shift_reg <= '0' & shift_reg(9 downto 1);

Comment: your logic saving suggestion might not work since the computation of busy signal becomes more complicated

Comment: what happens if 'shift_reg' is not zero initially, as in the case of ASIC instead of FPGA ? How does this affect the UART receiver on the other side of the channel ?